# Is Google Analytics' User ID Web Tracking avaible?

Tags: google-analytics

I read [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id) that you can set user id for new universal analytics.

**But** `The User-ID feature is currently in closed beta and not available to all users.`

Do you know how to get in this closed beta or is this document maybe out of date and it's already avaible for us that use universal analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't opt-in for this beta. Beta programs you can opt-in are displayed with a link to the beta sign up form.

Comment: That means I still have to do this via custom dimension?

Comment: Yes or you wait until this feature is available as an open beta.

Comment: When I do it with custom dimensions, I've to do the switch later to this feature and then do some magic to exported data thought. Because you can't tell google analytics to until this date this data and then another data origin.

Comment: @jurk: do you thing [google privacy policy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6958176/430112) will affect using user id in custom variable.